# Comparing cluster in a box-plot distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

My small subset dataframe. Here my data is I have done correlation and then clustering which resulted in different clusters. So each cluster consists of samples and genes as shown in the dataframe.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Gene = c("RPL23P8", "SLPI", "SNORA75", "GNLY", 
"HIF3A", "NR4A3", "HSPA8P1", "PPP1R16B", "CTD-2017F17.2", "WNK2"
), Cluster = c("cluster5", "cluster2", "cluster5", "cluster3", 
"cluster4", "cluster4", "cluster5", "cluster3", "cluster3", "cluster3"
), VC_VD3_1_S11 = c(3.92251966615359, 7.62457395344698, -0.072218459078315, 
5.41710968429767, 2.85043625409202, 4.31548046227268, 2.9417500069441, 
10.2087314584304, 5.83043427338657, 3.94255105962159), VC_VD3_2_S12 = c(3.49810677904462, 
7.45992335635171, -0.07676599362696, 5.50632660118593, 2.46157070921491, 
4.36194140644513, 2.56115955611891, 10.1179587476756, 5.65659383063399, 
4.34291522184012), X60A_VD3_1 = c(3.44877224221348, 7.21407156337612, 
-0.075458288620277, 6.37719420847396, 3.85202031120907, 6.05771783673217, 
2.27877793225076, 11.1899603708797, 5.55671708514997, 5.18097744734467
), X60A_VD3_2 = c(3.60530681382135, 7.83164953225347, -0.07145709822479, 
6.19998674869017, 3.40381010553138, 6.05979762619369, 2.42641639565238, 
10.8121439299102, 6.30585110649853, 5.18230568857803), B20_S19 = c(5.32662545428642, 
7.10121500395825, 0.144489851070829, 4.12301934219717, 2.02120971623758, 
3.69153546294403, 3.90551079854052, 7.87663745372051, 3.54154113705797, 
3.19841108123568), B21_S20 = c(5.44025594931395, 7.04503837689715, 
0.076547754058412, 4.22606899277924, 2.02274708821425, 3.23904160990358, 
3.40127039997972, 7.80829246192362, 4.05923739737225, 2.69799308052974
), B22_S21 = c(5.14997744544354, 7.17072165962234, 0.212467503648434, 
3.90312556058834, 2.02385441577774, 3.97284193508077, 3.1569530014282, 
8.07637586556023, 3.46141509289596, 2.89631644008723), X60A_KD1 = c(4.17948955277467, 
9.064371132843, 0.043521334810531, 5.66271338452076, 2.35482375745917, 
5.20439617718638, 2.97602337468434, 10.2659817754378, 5.10974391597121, 
3.43915429511049), X60A_KD2 = c(3.5962104032002, 8.78799571080207, 
0.037469752518227, 6.43301415158727, 2.98659724875229, 5.55982238352215, 
2.5293293843845, 10.0540465339726, 6.43364680262263, 3.24019184159299
)), row.names = c(45L, 458L, 290L, 779L, 1074L, 1127L, 27L, 900L, 
987L, 976L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code

```
df_melt = melt(df, id.vars=c("Gene","Cluster"))

ggplot(df_melt, aes(Cluster,value)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width=.5)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable), position = position_dodge2(preserve = "total"))+
  facet_wrap(~ Cluster) +
  
  #scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","dodgerblue4","red")) + #for boxplot
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","brown","maroon1","darkgreen","grey","navyblue","dodgerblue4","red"))+
  stat_summary(fun =median, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group = 1))+
  #geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.0001),size=.00001)+
  #theme_bw(base_size=15)+
  theme_bw()+
  
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, size=25, face="bold", hjust = 1), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0, size=35, face="bold", vjust=0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(size=40, face="bold"), 
        legend.title=element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size=unit(1, "cm"),      #Sets overall area/size of the legend
        legend.text=element_text(size=30)) +
  
  labs(x="Cell_Type", y=expression(paste("Expression"), title="Expression")) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

Which gives me something like this

[image: figure]

Now is there anyway where I can compare if there a difference between clusters? and show in the same figure.

Comment: So you're actually looking for an appropriate statistical test...?

Comment: Isn't it something that Kruskall wallis test can answer?? You can actually automatically perform it with ggplot

Comment: No im looking how to implement cluster wise for example I want to compare pairwise between all the clusters..how to do that..